# Run aggregate functions on grouped records unique values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, having

This should be a fairly simple task. I could complete it with a `cursor` but I really want to do it as a regular `query`. Table abstract is as follows: `CustId`, `ProductId`, `OrderId`, `UnitPrice`, `LineTotal`. I need to get `SUM()` of all `LineTotal` and `COUNT()` of all unique `OrderId` for each `CustId` and `ProductId` where `ProductId` is the same on at least 2 different `OrderId`. My query was like one below but upon verification I realized that uniqueness of `OrderId` is compromised so `aggregate` functions return incorrect results. Please advise.

```
SELECT h.CustId
    , h.ProductId
    , h.COUNT(DISTINCT h.OrderId)
    , h.SUM(h.LineTotal)
FROM History h
GROUP BY h.CustId
    , h.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(h.OrderId) > 1
```

Comment: share sample data and expected output

Comment: If you add in some example input data, and the result you'd expect, it will be a lot easier to understand what you mean...  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Your query is not even valid SQL.  It is impossible to know what you are really asking without sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had ran query with `HAVING COUNT() h.OrderId)` and forgot to type it out in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.OrderId) > 2` and not `HAVING COUNT(h.OrderId) > 1`, isn't this that *2 different OrderId* means? If not use `> 1` but keep `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT h.CustId
    , h.ProductId
    , h.COUNT(DISTINCT h.OrderId)
    , h.SUM(h.LineTotal)
FROM History h
GROUP BY h.CustId
    , h.ProductId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT h.OrderId) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

> where ProductId is the same on at least 2 different OrderId.

You need to enforce this requirement with an `IN(sub-query)` (or `EXISTS()` would also work) construct instead of HAVING.  This is because you are grouping by `ProductId` and `CustId`, but this requirement is on `ProductId` only, and should not be affected by `CustId`.

In psuedocode

```
WHERE ProductId IN (SELECT ProductIds that have at least 2 different OrderIds)
```

Comment: I wouldn't rely on that understanding.  The OP is too vague, and the note that `I realized that uniqueness of OrderId is compromised so aggregate functions return incorrect results` is inconsistent with this interpretation.

Comment: @MatBailie It's possible; I initially read both possible interpretations.   I decided that this was the more likely issue.  It seems more likely to me that OP is incorrectly interpreting the reason for the unexpected results, and less likely that he knew to use `COUNT DISTINCT` in the SELECT list, but not in the HAVING clause.